# 'System.IO.FileLoadException' when reference a web app in a console app

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a web app(asp.net-core-mvc) and a console app (.net core console). I am trying to make a reference to my web app in my console app. I have added a reference, and i can use the methods in my web app from my console app.

But when i try to get in touch with my database, then it fails.

```
client = DocumentClientManager.GetClient();
```

My DocumentClientManager only gets what environment my web app is running in. if it is dev, test or production

Then i return an endpoint, databaseid and so on

I can set a breakpoint on my client = DocumentClientManager.GetClient();
and i will reach it, but that is about it. Then i get an error in my Output window saying

```
'System.IO.FileLoadException' in ("web app.dll")
```

Anyone who got on clue on what i can do about it?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, Mags. Please consider adding the stacktrace of that exception to your question ([edit], don't comment).

Comment: What I believe is happening is the Web application is trying to read/write a file (maybe the configuration file) and either doesn't have permission or the file doesn't exist.  The file could be the database.  Can you debug the Web application at the same time as the console application using two instances of VS?

Comment: I found what i was missing. I was missing 3 Nugent packages.

Comment: So, now it works? That's odd. Never had that Exception when dependencies were missing.

Comment: The problem was i did not throw a exception, so i went to "Debug/Windows/Exception" and turn on exception for filenotLoadException. Which then showed that i didnt have a nugent package

Answer (score 0):

The problem was i didnt have 3 nugent packages. Now my problem is that i can.t call my web app due to the

```
var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
```

which when i comes from a console app returns null. Is there any workaround for that?

Comment: Please modify your question or even better: Delete this one and create a new question.

Comment: Okay, will do that

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the environment variable in console app.

e.g windows

C:/> set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development

C:/> dotnet run